# How to access request headers of shibboleth login in angular?

Tags: angular, shibboleth

I am developing an application in Angular in which I have to provide SSO mechanism using Shibboleth. The scenario is, when the user enters a specific URL (protected by shibboleth) it gets redirected to SSO, if the user is not already logged in. After signing in successfully the page gets redirected to angular. My question is, how can I retrieve shibboleth headers after the redirection in angular ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you can share any code already, please do so. That helps understanding the question and the context significantly.

You can check out this blogpost (https://medium.com/@philip_lysenko/initial-auth-with-angular-oauth2-a8740efe9264) which uses angular-oauth-oidc by Manfred Steyer (https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) and also works with redirectly and reads the response header

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am brainstorming the ideas right now to help me realise the flow. Thank you for providing the links.